# Display a field of one content type in another content type

Tags: entities

I am using drupal 7.I have created two custom content types Bank details and Loan offers.
Now in loan offers i want the logo of the bank to be displayed.The logo image is part of bank details content type.can it be done using node reference?I need help to resolve this issue.Thanks.

Comment: Have you completed this task?

Comment: I finished this by using node reference and relatioship in views.

Comment: Can you provide me the steps to do it. Or you have created a custom module for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a choice of modules for this:

- [References](http://drupal.org/project/references)
- [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)
- [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation)

Any one of those modules will allow you to create a field on your Loan Offers content type that references a Bank node. Then you can use Views/custom code/etc. to display the bank's image on the loan offer's node pages.