# Add below each node type A the related nodes of type B

Tags: nodes, views, entities

How can I do the following:

- Display all nodes of content type A (done!)
- Add underneath each node A fields of related nodes of type B (???)

I use Drupal 7 and Views 3. This [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/display-a-field-of-one-content-type-in-another-content-type) suggests the use of [Reference](https://drupal.org/project/references), [Entity Refrence](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) or [Relation](https://drupal.org/project/relation). However I cannot seem to make them work. 
Each node type A has a field refering to a type B node. How can I display fields of type B underneath each node type A?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best way, but if like you said, you already have a field in A that can be used to find one or more B, you already have a reference. At this point you only need to tell drupal to render all the B when it renders an A, and for that you to work with those kind of nodes templates.

Comment: So Astrayus I should add PHP to the templates of node A?

Comment: The "drupal way" should be: acquire the list of nodes B inside the preprocess function of node A and make it avaible for the node A template, but i never did it myself before so look into it better. Last, inside the node A template you add the usual print render( nodeB). You may need to create a template for node B too.

Comment: An example can be how nodes and node's comments work